# jpa pass reserved words in @Param String

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My goal is to write a query like:

```
select * from Book where  author = any(select author from book)
and(genre='comedy') order by ( '' )ASC, ( pages )DESC;
```

Where 'any(select author from book)' loses the single quotes so I can pass it thus

```
@Query("select b from Book b where b.author =:author and b.genre =:genre")
List<Book> findAllBySearch(@Param("author") String author,
                    @Param("genre") String genre);
```

The reason for doing this is because I have a form with 5 input criteria that may or may not be present and I don't want to write a separate query for each permutation. I know that one query with either the 'stringInput' or 'any(select criteria from book)' in case or null or empty string inserted before running the query.

I suppose using criteria API or something like that would allow building dynamic Query or inserting reserved sql words but I don't know how to implement it easily since I'm extending Spring data CrudRepository not using entitymanager...yet.... I suppose I will have to.

Does anyone know how to escape the '' imposed by string input @Param or what approach would easily work... such as Criteria API, Stored Procedure, Function ?

Please excuse my inexperience here...

Thanks !

It looks like the only way to do this with 5 possible inputs is to have the runtime strategy choose from 14 different queries depending on what inputs are present but I was trying to avoid this !!

Comment: I'm kind of doubting you want to unescape a variable (that's not what really happens with prepared statements anyway) that gets passed to your application. That's begging to be exploited.

Comment: if the column variable is '' I want  to select all of them so it's as if it wasn't a criteria and not a filter. If the variable is present then I will filter with it. Trying to do that by just inserting   --> any(select myColumn from book)...The reason is that it wasn't selected from a dropdown select on the form.

Comment: See section 3.6 in the Spring Data JPA docs I think is what you want. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: mmm CollinD  thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: Edited my comment to add a link to the correct section.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications would be a better idea. You can use specifications with CrudRepositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... here's the solution !

```
/**
 * A JPA-based implementation of the Book Service. Delegates to a JPA entity
 * manager to issue data access calls against the backing repository. The
 * EntityManager reference is provided by the managing container (Spring)
 * automatically.
 */
@Service("bookService")
@Repository
public class JpaBookService implements BookService {

private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public List<Book> searchBooks(String author, String genre, String pages, String year, String rating){

    List<Predicate> predList = new LinkedList<Predicate>();

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Book> c =cb.createQuery(Book.class);
    Root<Book> b = c.from(Book.class);

    if(author!="")
      predList.add(cb.equal(b.get("author"), author));
    }
    if(genre!=""){
      predList.add(cb.equal(b.get("genre"), genre));
    }
    if(pages!=""){
      predList.add(cb.equal(b.get("pages"), pages));
    }
    if(year!=""){
      predList.add(cb.equal(b.get("year"), year));
    }
    if(rating!=""){
      predList.add(cb.equal(b.get("rating"), rating));
    }
    Predicate[] predArray = new Predicate[predList.size()];
    predList.toArray(predArray);
    c.where(predArray);     

    TypedQuery<Book> q = em.createQuery(c);
    List<Book> result = q.getResultList();

    return result;

  }

}
```

Works good !

Johnny O.